# Selector in CSS is affecting other elements

Tags: html, css

This is my [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) code that is supposed to reformat links:

```
a {
color: #120000;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="intro" class="grid_9">
     <h1>This site just might change your life</h1>
     <p><a href="#" class=button>Browse Our Features</a></p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the header (but only this one) is being affected in the same way as the links. How can I fix this?

Comment: You forgot quotes in class=button

Comment: not enough information. everything looks fine, are you sure the `a` is affecting `h1` and not the other way around or that maybe both elements are possibly inheriting from `.grid_9` or a ccs style for `#intro`

Comment: I second what @fnostro says. You have something else going on. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/nz6nk/ Everything seems to be working fine

Comment: @Krimson that is really strange. My grid setup has nothing AFAIK that could affect it. I did change the quotes so syntax is correct. I am using a the downloadable css file normalize.css which possibly could be changing it, but I haven't been able to find where in that file it could be affecting it in such a way. I'm just starting to learn this stuff, so is there a way besides classes and ids that could group elements together that I may have done inadvertently? Edit: I actually forgot to close the link tag above this block of code, putting '<a/>' instead of '</a>' which was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to the `<a>` tags that should not follow it or use the existing one depending on whether or not that class is specifically for that purpose.  Then, use the `:not()` selector:

```
a:not(.button) {
    color: #120000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/654v7/)</kbd>

Also, the header would only follow the CSS for the `<a>` if it were wrapped in an `<a>` tag.  If this is true, give that `<a>` tag the set class.